# Is "Time is short and the water's risin'" a Southernism?

Tags: etymology, expressions, american-english, phrase-origin, dialects

My Georgia-born mother used to say, "Time is short and the water's risin'."

I think the expression was the title of a recent memoir, but couldn't find it on Amazon.

Is anyone familiar with its origin?

Comment: Lovely sentiment sounds like Seize the day as Noah's Flood is coming.

Comment: It would help if we knew when your mother was born, as well as if she was city or country.

Comment: @ab2 But when? And in Atlanta, or country? As they say in Atlanta..."Atlanta is _not_ Georgia." In other words, we do not have enough context.

Comment: I'm more familiar with "Lord willin' and the crick don't rise."  Used (in rural Kentucky, et al) to infer that a stated event will occur if nothing untoward prevents it.

Comment: @HotLicks You don't mean *infer*; you mean *imply*.

Comment: @Cascabel I think you meant 'Etlanna'

Comment: @tchrist - I thought I was doing pretty good to come up with "untoward".

Comment: @tchrist Good pick-up. I really like to keep this clip handy: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oYqHMBTtZsc :)

Answer (score 7):

The only thing I found is [this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0525220011):

> Time Is Short and the Water Rises, Operation Gwamba: The Story of the
>   Rescue of 10,000 Animals from Certain Death in a South American Rain
>   Forest.   Hardcover  – January, 1967
>
> by John Walsh (Author),    Robert Gannon (Author)

This seems too recent (1967) to be the source of a folk saying.  However, the title could come from an older saying, which I have not been able to find so far.

A candidate for an older saying which your mother and her neighbors might have adapted is:

> God willing and the creek don't rise

Sources: [World Wide Words](http://www.worldwidewords.org/qa/qa-god1.htm) and [Wikipedia, The creek don't rise](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_creek_don%27t_rise)

Note that *the time is short* is a Biblical saying (Paul, 1 Corinthians 7:29), which is extensively discussed at [Biblical Hermeneutics Stack Exchange](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/8654/what-does-paul-mean-when-he-says-the-time-is-short-in-1-corinthians-729).  It is thus possible that your mother's community combined a Biblical saying warning that time is short with an old regional saying about the rising [waters of the] creek (or crick).  More Research is Needed.

Comment: Not sure why you'd have to be very young for your mother to have adopted this phrase from a source cited in '67, that was 50 years ago. My mother hadn't even been born yet and I'm 30!

Comment: @talmu You are 30.  QED!  But I get your point.  I'll edit tomorrow.

Comment: Compare "God willing and the creek don't rise" to "Come Hell or high water".  It's reasonable to suspect that the former is derived from the latter as a somewhat milder assertion (though it's is no doubt possible that the reverse is true -- that the latter is derived from the former).

Comment: I remember my mother used to say this back in the early 1940s. I'm 80, and I have written about those days in a forthcoming Roman à clef.